# How to order products by meta key and show also products where this meta key is not set

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to order products by specific meta key but I want to show all products including those ones which has not set this meta key. I want to show products with set meta key first and then the rest of the products. 
Unfortunatelly this soluition woks only to show products whose has set that meta key:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args');

function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    global $wp_query;
    if (isset($_GET['orderby'])) {
        switch ($_GET['orderby']) :
            case 'myorder' :
                $args['order'] = 'DESC';
                $args['meta_key'] = 'myorder';
                $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
            break;
        endswitch;
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: This is actually a complex query, but I vaguely recall asking this before, so I know the answer is on this site somewhere, I just have to google my brain.

Comment: Found it [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/163708/6477). How it actually applies to WooCommerce sorting args is a bit beyond me this late at night, but I suspect you'd need to add it to `posts_where` for product queries.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I am not sure if this link helps me. It's for some table called dealer_pm. And I want order of WC products based on post meta and actually I don't understand SQL very well.

Comment: `dealer_pm` is just an SQL shortcut for the post meta table. I'm not great with SQL either, that's why I had to post the question. :) I'm not saying you can just cut/paste that code and it will work for you. I'm saying that a similar `post_clause` will be needed to order by a meta key even when the meta value does not exist. An easier alternative might be to always save a meta value, then you can use the code you have without dealing with SQL.

Comment: Actually I solved it by adding the searched meta value to default 0 after creating product. This is fit for me.

Comment: Yup, that way is *much* easier. :) No SQL required.